# How to check null values using Mockobject for the real object?

Tags: java, mockito

I am writing Mockito for the following code, but somehow for the null and empty checks, it's giving error.

How can I debug this?

```
public boolean isValid(StudentDto dto) {
        return (dto.getFirstName().isEmpty() && dto.getlastName().isEmpty() 
                && dto.getEmailId().isEmpty() && dto.getAddress().isEmpty()
                && dto.getPhone().isEmpty() && dto.getCity().isEmpty());
    }


public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> saveStudent(@Valid StudentDto dto) {
    if(isValid(dto)) {
        log.error(env.getProperty("error.errors"), env.getProperty("error.missing.input.parameters"));
        throw new NotFoundException(env.getProperty("error.missing.input.parameters"), BusinessErrorCode.MISSING_REQUIRED_INPUTS);
    }

    // Convert to entity
    Student student = convertToEntity(dto);

    try {
        studentRepository.save(student);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(env.getProperty("error.errors"), env.getProperty("error.db.exception"));
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, env.getProperty("error.db.exception"), ex);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Test Classes:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({})
public class StudentServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    private StudentRepository studentRepositoryMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Mock
    private Student studentMock;

    // Define the Environment as a Mockito mock object
    @Mock 
    private Environment env;

    @Mock
    private StudentDto studentDtoMock;

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();



    // Test case for SaveStudent
    @Test
    public void testSaveStudent() {
        when(divisionService.isValid(studentDtoMock)).thenReturn(true);

        assertEquals(new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.OK).getStatusCode(), 
                divisionService.saveStudent(studentDtoMock).getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use below and it works fine.

```
public boolean isValid(StudentDto dto) {
        return StringUtils.isEmpty(dto);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without checking null for `StudentDto`, you referring the fields for this object. First you need to check `dto==null` then refer the fields of dto. Other wise it may give exception.
Your method `isValid` could be :

```
public boolean isValid(StudentDto dto) {
    return (dto==null||((dto.getFirstName().isEmpty() && dto.getlastName().isEmpty() 
            && dto.getEmailId().isEmpty() && dto.getAddress().isEmpty()
            && dto.getPhone().isEmpty() && dto.getCity().isEmpty())));
}
```

Comment: This is still not working in my case. Not sure what is causing the issue

Comment: Can you please guide me what mistake is still happening ?